# Electrum "Pending" what does it mean

Tags: electrum

My balance in Electrum shows "pending." What does pending mean?

Comment: Electrum works well for me, but does have its quirks. What were or did you do before this happened? Did you btc in there? try restarting it.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Currency wallets show as 'pending' until enough transactions have happened AFTER that one in the block chain.  It is a feature to prevent false sends and doubble spends of wallet to wallet transactions.  Not all wallets let you know how many more blocks need to come after to ensure the transaction is a valid one.  Time and patience will eventualy show that it is complete.  If it is still ' pending ' after 48 hours, contact the other party to see if there is an issue at their end.